# Prevent CMake from modifying include directories?

Tags: cmake

Consider the following example:

`CmakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

project(my_project)
message("PROJECT_NAME is '${PROJECT_NAME}'")

set(my_incls "D:/msys64/usr/include" "D:/msys64/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include")
message("my_incls ${my_incls}")

add_library(test main.c)
target_include_directories(test PRIVATE ${my_incls})
get_target_property(libincl test INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message("libincl ${libincl}")
```

`main.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>

const char greeting[] = "hello world";

int main() {
    printf("%s!\n", greeting);
    return 0;
}
```

I do this in MSYS2 bash shell on Windows 10, relative to the folder the above files are in:

```bash
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../ -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

The output of cmake is:

```
$ cmake ../ -G "Unix Makefiles"
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
...
PROJECT_NAME is 'my_project'
my_incls D:/msys64/usr/include;D:/msys64/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include
libincl /tmp/cmake_test/D:/msys64/usr/include;/tmp/cmake_test/D:/msys64/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include
-- Configuring done
...
```

So, you can see that in `my_incls` the folder paths are listed exactly as specified - but once they have been set as `target_include_directories` and are read back for printing, they have been changed: namely `/tmp/cmake_test` (the current working directory - the folder where I placed the files given above) has been prepended to the paths as specified, making them totally unusable.

How can I prevent CMake from modifying paths that I've specified for `target_include_directories`?

Comment: Windows paths (the ones which starts with the driver letter) does not work on Linux and on WSL. You need to use paths like `/mnt/d/msys64/usr/include` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev - under MINGW64's `cmake` there is a 'MSYS Makefiles' generator which probably takes this into account, but there is none such generator in MSYS2's `cmake`. Still, I'd expect it should be possible, that it is up to *me* to specify correct paths, without `cmake` making assumptions and changing my paths; at least it should let me change the prefix it prepends in case it guessed wrong. Is there really no way to prevent `cmake` from changing include paths?

Comment: "Still, I'd expect it should be possible, that it is up to me to specify correct paths, without cmake making assumptions and changing my paths" - CMake doesn't make *assumptions*. The command `target_include_directories` accepts absolute paths and relative ones. The path `D:/msys64/..` is not absolute on Linux, so CMake interprets it as a relative path, and transforms into the absolute one (the property `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` contains only absolute paths).

Comment: To me it looks like you shouldn't be specifying those paths as include directories anyways, but set [`CMAKE_SYSROOT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html) to `D:/msys64` (or WSL equivalent?) in a toolchain file. Not sure if this works for `.../glib-2.0/include` too...

Comment: "under MINGW64's `cmake` there is a 'MSYS Makefiles' generator which probably takes this into account, but there is none such generator in MSYS2's `cmake`." - MSYS2 [documentation](https://www.msys2.org/docs/cmake/) suggests to use CMake from the package `mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake`. According to that documentation, that CMake should support `MSYS Makefiles` generator. As for CMake from MSYS [environment](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/), it probably targets creation of binaries for Cygwin-emulated environment only. So it has only generators suitable for Linux.